# Land Prediction Logistic Regression

Tags: land-cover, terrset

I use terrset idrisi software to create land cover prediction map for the year 2023 in *land change modeler*. I am trying to do this by implementing logistic regression which is in *transition-sub model structure* part in transition-potentials tab. I would like to tell you the steps clearly:

1. Earlier land cover image is Landuse_2007.
2. Later land cover image is Landuse_2014

Until here, I don't encounter any problem. Change map is created. My transition sub-model is *from barrenland to urban*. In transition-sub model structure part, I put *distance_to_road* and *distance_to urban* variables there and at the logistic regression text results, pseudo r squared is equal to 0.9997.

Prediction map for 2023 is like this:

[image]

[image]
[image]

**How can I erase this pink horizontal line from my prediction map?**

Comment: Are you sure those lines are not coming from one of your input rasters? I have had  an similar experience when rasterizing some polygon shapefiles.